# Wolfram alpha query works online but not through mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations, wolfram-alpha-queries

Bit of a bizarre problem I'm having (well, more a question than a problem). I am trying to solve an integral, which I queried using the online wolfram alpha website. The input and output are interpreted correctly and I get what I want.

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28b+%2B+%28h+t%29%2FT%29*Exp%5B+-2*Pi*i*f*t%5D%2C+%7Bt%2C+-W%2C+-W+-+T%7D%5D](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28b%20%2B%20%28h%20t%29%2FT%29*Exp%5B%20-2*Pi*i*f*t%5D%2C%20%7Bt%2C%20-W%2C%20-W%20-%20T%7D%5D)
[image]

Now I want to do the exact same thing by calling wolfram alpha in mathematica (using ==).
However, when I type == and then use the same copyable plaintext offered by the url above, all of a sudden I get the error that Wolfram|Alpha doesn't know how to interpret my input, and the input interpretation is just 'f' (screenshot attached)
[image]

Why does it work without issue on the wolfram alpha web-page but not when I try to use wolfram alpha through mathematica?
Thanks

Comment: MMA version 12.1. Just tried and can not reproduce the error. Instead I get the input back with an "+" at the right upper edge, where I can choose the format of the output.

Comment: In version 12 on m1 ARM, the code doesn't give any errors, assumes that i is complex...then fails to load the the result....however when clicking the given link, it forwards to wolfram alpha in the browser, which then loads correctly...so in v12 there is a similar issue.

Comment: Just tried this on Mathematica 12 instead of Mathematica 10, I just get the input back again but it does not load the actual answer.